# Java: Is it possible to compare String values in two arrays, and if they match, increment an int value in the first array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I'd like to build an arraylist by adding an array composed of `String name, double price, int quantity` representing different items. If an item is added which is identical to one that is already in the arraylist, it should increment `quantity` instead of being added.

My thought process was to check if the values for index 1 between 2 arrays match, and if they do, increment the value for index 3 in the first array. Is this something that's possible to do in Java? How would you compare a new array to arrays already in a list?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but not in your way. How do you think to _compose_ the array with different types?

Comment: Do you really need a list for this? Could this not be fields in a class? Or do you have different "items"? Then maybe a list of item objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably review your model and use an object.

Create a class containing your three attributes. Then a `Map<String, YourObject>`. Then when you want to add your Object just do a test before

```
if(map.containsKey(objectName)) {
    YourObject object = map.get(objectName);
    object.setQuantity(object.getQuantity() + 1);
}
```

**EDIT** After discussing with @Eugene

```
YourObject objectToAdd = ...
Map<String, YourObject> map = new HashMap<>();
...
YourObject objectInMap = map.get(objectName);
if(objectInMap != null) {
    // increase Quantity in objectInMap 
} else {
    //Object not existing in the map, never added
    //manage initial quantity here
    map.put(objectToAdd.getName(), objectToAdd)
}
```

Comment: why `Map` and not a `Set`?

Comment: With the Map you can directly check the "identifier" of the object, here probably the name. For the Set you would have to override the equals method to make sure it does not compare the instance but the specific value inside the object... more complex, not necessarily clean

Comment: interesting that you are saying "cleaner", but show an example using `contains`, when you really want just a `get`; otherwise I hardly agree with u

Comment: You are right it is not `contains` but `containsKey`. I'll edit. Thks! You actually do not want to compare the whole object but just the identifier, whichever it is

Comment: still nope - doing `containsKey` if that gives you `true` - what would you have to do next to update the entry inside the `HashMap`?

Comment: I am not sure to understand, if the test is true then `map.get(objectName).incrementQuantity()` else `map.put(objectName, object)`

Comment: you are doing two hash look-ups this way, one for `containsKey` and one for `get` - when you could do only `get`, if it returns null - you did not had it, if it returns != null - you have it, so simply update it. No need to call `put` after that. And that makes it cleaner in your opinion...

Comment: You are right about the hash look- ups, probably more efficient to do the `get` and test the `null` value. But the `put` is required I think, to add the object in the map if it is not in here yet. I'll update the code

Comment: Beyond that: a nice answer so have my vote. And thanks for leaving out the "how to do really do this" part ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be to build a `POJO` holding those values:

```
class Purchase {

    String name;
    // all other

}
```

And override `equals/hashCode` with `name` and `price` (NOT `quantity` since that is an updatable field), then put those instances into a `Set` for fast search. The rest is probably obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to the other answers: step 1 is to define a class that represents such a `SalesActivity`.

But in contrast to the others, I suggest: make all fields of such an object final. Meaning: instead of *incrementing* the `amount` field when more X items are sold ... simply create a *new* SalesActivity.

And you just keep adding these new objects to your list. And when you want to know "gosh, how many X where sold", you simply iterate that list, and for any X entry, you add up the `quantity` information.

Of course, this is not how you do model things in a newbie exercise. But that is how you *should* do things in the real world. You avoid objects that carry state. It is like your bank account: that isn't an object that changes its state. It is nothing but an endlessly increased series of "account activities". In other words: there is no field "account balance" in an account object. But a list of deposits and payments, and the balance is nothing but the "sum" of all these events at a specific point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, well... I wrote the code considering already existing answers (I was bored)...

Here you are:

```
public class Helper {

    private static List<MyData> addNewData(List<MyData> listOfData, MyData myData) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= listOfData.size(); i++) {
            if (listOfData.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(myData.getName())) {
                listOfData.get(i).setQuantity(listOfData.get(i).getQuantity() + myData.getQuantity());
                break; //the data with the same name is found
            } else {
                listOfData.add(myData);
                break; //also necessary break!!!
            }

        }
        return listOfData;
    }

    private static void printData(List<MyData> myData){
        myData.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("______________________");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //test data
        List<MyData> testData = new ArrayList<>();
        testData.add(new MyData("chair", 15.0, 44));
        testData.add(new MyData("bottle", 0.25, 119));


        System.out.println("Original data: "); printData(testData);
        //try to add new item (with new name)
        addNewData(testData, new MyData("glass", 1.1, 10));
        //print the new data
        System.out.println("New List: "); printData(testData);

        //try to add new 'existing' item
        addNewData(testData, new MyData("chair", 17.0, 4));
        //print the new - new data
        System.out.println("NEW new data: "); printData(testData);


    }

    static class MyData {

        private String name;
        private double price;
        private int quantity;

        //constructor without parameters
        public MyData() {
            this.setName("");
            this.setPrice(0.0d);
            this.setQuantity(0);
        }

        //constructor with parameters
        public MyData(String name, double price, int quantity) {
            this.setName(name);
            this.setPrice(price);
            this.setQuantity(quantity);
        }

        //getters, setters...
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return this.name + ", " + this.price + ", " + this.quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Original data: 
chair, 15.0, 44
bottle, 0.25, 119
______________________
New List: 
chair, 15.0, 44
bottle, 0.25, 119
glass, 1.1, 10
______________________
NEW new data: 
chair, 15.0, 48
bottle, 0.25, 119
glass, 1.1, 10
______________________
```

Please, notice that price of chair is unchanged (it could be done, as well...)!